# How can I change the length of photos in iMovie '13?

Tags: macos, imovie

I'm trying to make a simple iMovie time lapse video and it's my first time trying to iMovie '13. I have photos that I would like to change the duration of, only when I click the info icon there's just an image of a clock and no option to change the duration, which is how I've been directed on every other forum, only the option just isn't there. Any other ideas on how to change the time length of multiple photos at once?

Answer (score 11):

1. ⌘-click on all the pictures that you want to adjust the timing of in the timeline.
2. Go to **Window** → **Show Adjustments Bar** or press <kbd>3</kbd>.
3. Select the info button on the adjustments bar.
4. Enter the duration into the box on the right and press Enter.

   [image]

   This will change the duration of all the selected clips (or in this case, pictures).